# Comment form won't show on my wp blog posts

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I have a wordpress site with a customized theme, and I have included comments into my single.php file, which looks like this:

```
    <?php get_header();?>
<div id="content">
<div class="right">
<div class="article">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h1><?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
<small><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></small>
<?php the_content();?>
<br /><br />
<hr />
<br /><br />
<?php comments_template(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>

<?php endif; ?>
</div></div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Still, the comment form won't show up underneath my blog posts. I have enabled comments in the back end.

Comment: post the plugin's name you are using for this form.

Comment: I am using (atleast trying to) the built-in comment system that comes with wordpress. As for plugins: I tried several comment plugins and none of them worked, so there's definitely something wrong, but everything else on the site works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't Know your template code it is correct or no but your code contain error because you used error position to put comment template code

put the comment template code outside the loop and within the `container` class
like this

```
<?php get_header();?>
<div id="content">
<div class="right">
<div class="article">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h1><?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
<small><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></small>
<?php the_content();?>
<br /><br />
<hr />
<br /><br />

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>

<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php comments_template(); ?>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

My code
this code within `comments.php` file

```
<?php
/* Prevent the direct loading of comments.php */
if (!empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT-FILENAME']) && basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT- FILENAME']) == 'comments.php')  {
die(__('You can not access this file directly.', 'Yallanpe-Theme'));
}
/* If the post is password protected then display text and return */
if(post_password_required()) : ?>
<h5>
<?php 
    _e('This Post is password protected, Enter the password to view the  comments', 'Yallanpe-Theme'); 
    return; 
?>
</h5>
<?php endif;
/* If we have comments to display, we display them */
if(have_comments()) : ?>
<div id="comments-container">
    <?php wp_list_comments( array('walker' => new YPE_walker_comment)); ?>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#comments-container ul#comment-list li.depth-1 .comment-avatar  img").addClass("img-thumbnail");
            $("#comments-container ul#comment-list li.depth-1 ul.children  .comment-avatar img").addClass("img-circle");
        });
    </script>
</div><!-- /#comments-container -->
<?php if (get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option('page_comments')) : ?>
    <div class="comments-nav-section">
        <h5 class="text-left"><?php previous_comments_link(__('&larr; Older Comments', 'Yallanpe-Theme')); ?></h5>
        <h5 class="text-right"><?php next_comments_link(__('Newer Comments &rarr;', 'Yallanpe-Theme')); ?></h5>
    </div><!-- end comment-nav-section -->
<?php endif; ?>
<?php 
/* If we don't have comments and the comments are closed, display a text */
elseif (!comments_open() && !is_page() &&  post_type_supports(get_post_type(), 'comments')) : ?>
<h5> <?php _e('Comments are Closed.', 'Yallanpe-Theme'); ?> </h5>
<?php endif; 
/* Display the comment form */
comment_form();
?>
```

and this code below within `functions.php` (I used Bootstarp framework for comment form)

```
<?php

class YPE_walker_comment extends Walker_Comment {

var $tree_type = 'comment';
var $db_fields = array( 'parent' => 'comment_parent', 'id' => 'comment_ID'    );

function __construct() { ?>
    <h4>Comments</h4>
    <ul id="comment-list">
<?php }
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {       
    $GLOBALS['comment_depth'] = $depth + 1; ?>
    <ul class="children">
<?php }
function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $GLOBALS['comment_depth'] = $depth + 1; ?>
    </ul>
<?php }
function start_el( &$output, $comment, $depth, $args, $id = 0 ) {
    $depth++;
    $GLOBALS['comment_depth'] = $depth;
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; 
    $parent_class = (empty($args['has_children']) ? '' : 'parent'); ?>

    <li <?php comment_class($parent_class); ?> id="comment-<?php  comment_ID() ?>">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="comment-avatar">
                    <?php
                        $avatar_size = 80;
                        if ($comment->comment_parent != 0) { $avatar_size =  80; }
                        echo get_avatar($comment, $avatar_size);
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-10">
                 <div class="comment-header">
                    <?php
                        $reply_args = array(
                            'add_below' => $add_below, 
                            'depth' => $depth,
                            'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] 
                        );
                    ?>
                        <ul id='author-time' class="list-inline">
                            <li><?php echo get_comment_author_link(); ?> </li>
                            <li class="pull-right text-muted"><?php  comment_date(); ?> at <?php comment_time(); ?></li>
                        </ul>
                        <em>
                            <ul id="reply-delete" class="list-inline">
                                <li><?php  comment_reply_link(array_merge($args, $reply_args)); ?></li>
                                <?php if (current_user_can('edit_post')) {   $id = get_comment_ID(); ?>
                                    <li><?php echo ' <a   href="'.admin_url("comment.php?action=editcomment&c=$id").'">Edit</a>'; ?></li>
                                    <li><?php echo ' <a href="'.admin_url("comment.php?action=cdc&c=$id").'">Delete</a>'; ?></li>
                                    <li><?php echo ' <a href="'.admin_url("comment.php?action=cdc&dt=spam&c=$id").'">Spam</a>'; ?></li>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </ul>
                        </em>
                </div>

                <div class="comment-content">
                    <?php 
                        if( !$comment->comment_approved ) : ?>
                        <em class="text-muted">
                            <?php _e('Your comment is awaiting moderation.',  'Yallanpe Theme'); ?>
                        </em>
                    <?php else: comment_text(); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php }
    function end_el( &$output, $comment, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) { ?>
    </li> 
<?php }
    function __destruct() { ?>
    </ul>
<?php }
}

function YPE_custom_comment_form($defaults) {
$comment_notes_after = '';
$defaults ['comment_notice_before'] = '';
$defaults ['comment_notes_after'] = $comment_notes_after;
$defaults ['id_form'] = 'commentform';
$defaults ['comment_field'] = '<p class="form-group">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span></span>
                                                <textarea class="form- control" name="comment" id="comment" cols="30" rows="10">
                                                </textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </p>';
$defaults ['label_submit']  = 'Submit Comment';
$defaults ['title_reply']   = '<section id="comment-form"><h4>Add  Comment</h4></section>';

return $defaults;
}

add_filter ('comment_form_defaults', 'YPE_custom_comment_form');


function YPE_custom_comment_fields() {
$commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();
$req       = get_option('require_name_email');
$aria_req  = ($req ? " aria-required='true'" : '');

$fields = array(
    'author' => '<div class="form-group">' .
                    '<p>'.
                        '<div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>' .
                                    '<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="author" name="author" value="'. esc_attr($commenter['comment_author']) .'"  '. $aria_req .' placeholder="Enter Your Name" />'.
                            '</div>'.
                        '</div>'.
                    '</p>'.
                '</div>',
    'email' => '<div class="form-group">' .
                    '<p>'.
                        '<div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>' .
                                    '<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="email" name="email" value="'. esc_attr($commenter['comment_author_email'])  .'" '. $aria_req .' placeholder="Enter Your Email" />'.
                            '</div>'.
                        '</div>'.
                    '</p>'.
                '</div>',
    'url' => '<div class="form-group">' .
                    '<p>'.
                        '<div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span></span>' .
                                    '<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="url" name="url" value="'.esc_attr($commenter['comment_author_url']) .'"  placeholder="Enter Your Website URL" />'.
                            '</div>'.
                        '</div>'.
                    '</p>'.
                '</div>',

);
return $fields;
}

add_filter ('comment_form_default_fields', 'YPE_custom_comment_fields');


?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit! But I am still not able to see the comment form underneith my blog post.

Comment: Must be you has error in comment template code the because the above code it is correct must the comment template outside the loop if don't work  your template code it is contained errors if you ant i take you the full code i used in my theme

Comment: the `comments_template();` it is accept two parameters (optional) but if you used different file name for comment codes such us `my-comment.php` you must point to the file name in first parameter like `comments_template( '/my-comment.php' );` the default name of comment file is `comments.php`

Comment: Yes, I tried several solutions for my comments.php file, and also copied the comments.php from the twentythirteen template. Did not work. Should I make some edits to the twentythirteen template?

Comment: do you active comments from your admin panel?

Comment: Yes, comments are active from the backend problem. I really need help with this one, and cannot understand what is wrong!

Comment: I Added my comment form and comment template in my theme for above post you can used it